# Enabling or installing network access tools in nautilus

Tags: networking, nautilus

Recently I had done `remove --purge` blue-tooth manager as my laptop doesn't have blue-tooth device. Now when I try to access a windows share from ubuntu I get this error.

```
Cannot display "smb://192.168.0.10"
 Nautilus cannot handle "smb" locations.
```

When I open `Places -> Connect to Server` no options under `service type: custom location` (for example: samba, ftp, ssh) are listed. It's completely empty. How can I get those network tools back in nautilus?

Edit 1: Here is the output of the command posted by oli in the comments:

```
gvfs                                            install
gvfs-bin                                        install
gvfs-fuse                                       install
libgnome-vfs2.0-cil                             install
libgnome2-vfs-perl                              install
libgnomevfs2-0                                  install
libgnomevfs2-common                             install
libgnomevfs2-extra                              install
libgvfscommon0                                  install
libnautilus-extension1                          install
nautilus                                        install
nautilus-data                                   install
nautilus-image-converter                        install
nautilus-sendto                                 install
nautilus-sendto-empathy                         install
nautilus-share                                  install
```

Comment: It's hard to know in which state is your system with this info. Can you please post the output of dpkg --get-selections | grep naut and dpkg --get-selections | grep vfs

Comment: Or just: `dpkg --get-selections | grep -E '(naut|vfs)'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like gvfs-backends was removed when you purge libbluetooth3, you can put it back by running the following:

`sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends`

Restart your computer for best effect. See more details about gvfs here:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Gvfs